# How to fix my Honda Ballade. 92 Model (Luxline)

Tags: engine, noise, smoke, crankshaft

I drive a Honda and the crank shaft makes a lot of noise especially during high acceleration and it smokes white from the exhaust. Someone said I should just get a new engine as this a typical problem with Honda Ballade that are older.

What can I do to fix my car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. White smoke is often an indication of coolant entering the combustion chamber. We need much more detail to be able to start answering your question. Why do you say the "*crank shaft makes a lot of noise*"? How did you determine it is the crankshaft? Can you describe the noise (clanking, knocking, grinding, swishing, etc.)? How many miles (km) are on this engine? How long have you been driving it in this condition? Is there coolant in the oil? Is there oil in the coolant? Please use the [edit] feature to add these details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 2 things:

- **white smoke:** this usually indicates you are burning coolant. This generally indicates a worn out head gasket. Inspect your engine oil for cream-looking foamy floaters, and inspect your coolant for clumps of oil floating.
- **getting a new engine:** well, the thing is, there's no such thing as a new engine for a '92 Ballade. You'd be getting someone else's old engine, which may or may not have something wrong with it. Don't believe in warranties on used engines, and don't believe in "rebuilt" engines unless there's paperwork for all the parts they've replaced and the machining they've done. With some diagnosis time, you can find exactly what's wrong with yours, and unless the block is warped from overheating (a common cause of head gasket fialures), it would most likely be easier, cheaper and less risky to repair or rebuild your engine rather than throw a dice on a used engine.